# Serialising multiple return types with Request.CreateResponse

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have an action method for an API that returns an HttpResponseMessage, however based on the Accept header this can return many different formats of data.

This is what I have at the moment, which does work, but it's not very desirable, as I'll have to remember to include any new classes in the MappedItem method, and there will be lots.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        var result = _builder.Build(id);

        return MappedItem(result);
    }

    protected HttpResponseMessage MappedItem<T>(T item)
    {
        // Maps the class to the media type defined in the Accept header
        var destinationType = GetDestinationType();
        var type = typeof(T);
        var mapped = Mapper.Map(item, type, destinationType);

        if (mapped is ApiModelV1) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mapped as ApiModelV1);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mapped);
    }
```

It works fine without the `if (mapped is ApiModelV1)` part if I'm just serialising to JSON, but throws an exception if I'm serialising to XML. Does anyone know a way of doing this in a more generic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found a solution, although I've had to resort to using reflection, as I couldn't get it working properly with known types.

```
protected HttpResponseMessage MappedItem<T>(T item)
{
    var destinationType = GetDestinationType();
    var type = typeof(T);
    var mapped = Mapper.Map(item, type, destinationType);

    MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("CreateResponse", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    method = method.MakeGenericMethod(mapped.GetType());

    return (HttpResponseMessage)method.Invoke(this, new[] {mapped});
}

public HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse<T>(T obj)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, obj);
}
```

It's not ideal, but it's far more favourable than having lots of `if (mapped is ...)` for every type that I want to serialise.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to decorate your base class with the [`KnownType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute and list all possible derived classes to indicate to the XML serializer about the existence of those types:

```
[KnownType(typeof(ApiModelV1))]
[KnownType(typeof(ApiModelV2))]
public class BaseClass
{
    ...
}
```

Alternatively if you don't want to pollute your models with such attributes you could use a custom XML serializer and indicate the known types:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var knownTypes = new Type[]
        {
            typeof(ApiModelV1),
            typeof(ApiModelV2),
        };

        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<BaseClass>(
            new DataContractSerializer(typeof(BaseClass), knownTypes)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although if I use the KnownType attribute, then XML output has uses the d1p1 namespace on everything. The only way I could get it to output something was to use a custom serialiser and then say `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mapped as BaseModel);` but then the root element is named "BaseModel".